# How to display data inside table by ng-repeat using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help i need to display data inside table using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.listOfData=[
             {
         {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':1111},
         {'date':'2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':2222}
      },
     {
         {'date':'2016-01-23 13:15:59','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':3333},
         {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':4444}
     }
]
```

my html table is given below.

```
<div class="table-responsive dashboard-demo-table">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Date</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Name</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Email</td>
                <td colspan="7">Order</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Order Id</td>
              <td>Order status</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>date</td>
              <td>name</td>
              <td>email</td>
              <td>orderid</td>
              <td>orderstatus</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

> expected output result.

```
date                name        email                     order
                                                    order_id     order_status

2016-01-25          raj          raj@gmail.com          1111        1
 to 2016-02-04                                           2222       0
```

The above table is for serial no-1 again for sl no-2 the data will display accordingly.
Here i need suppose 0th index of `$scope.listOfData` has two set of data some field value like `name,email` are same so these two sate of data will join and it will display in 1st index of the table.Here date column will contain lower date to higher date like(`from date to todate`),name and email filed will contain the value one but here different is for `order` column `order_id and order_status` is different for each set of data of 0th index from `$scope.listOfData` so these will again move in a another loop.Please help me.

Comment: the -1 wasn't nice, this question is fair, it's about showing pair of rows together in a table not so easy to do if you're not used too angular.

Answer (score 0):

The following may help you

```
<div ng-repeat="data in listOfData">
  <!--<Do whatever you need here with data.name, data.date etc...>-->
  <!--You can keep your table here.-->
</div>
```

Comment: No,I think its not like that so simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in listOfData">
          <td>{{data.date}}</td><td>{{data.name}}</td>....
</tr>
```

PS for header you can use a <thead> tag

Edit :

```
 {
     {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':1111},
     {'date':'2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':2222}
  }
```

You can't with your json format like this, flatten it in a one level array with even index containing "from" and odd containing "to" datas then do the following

```
    <tr ng-repeat="data in listOfData">
          <td ng-if="$index %2==0">{{data.date}}</td>
           <td ng-if="$index %2==1">To {{data.date}}</td>
           ...
  </tr>
```

EDIT : can't really make a plunker, here is what by flatten I mean transform this

```
$scope.listOfData=[
         [
     {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':1111},
     {'date':'2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':2222}
  },
 {
     {'date':'2016-01-23 13:15:59','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':3333},
     {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':4444}
 ]
]
```

Into this :

```
$scope.listOfData=[  
     {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':1111},
     {'date':'2016-02-04 11:26:05','name':'raj','email':'raj@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':2222},
     {'date':'2016-01-23 13:15:59','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':1,'order_id':3333},
     {'date':'2016-01-25 18:14:00','name':'rahul','email':'rahul@gmail.com','order_status':0,'order_id':4444}
    }
]
```

So your "from" lines will have even index (0,2,4...) and your "to" lines will have the odds ones (1,3,5,...).

Using $index you can now built properly your lines : $index is given by ng-repeat. ng-if is a directive that won't build the dom element if the condition is not true.

So this

```
<td ng-if="$index %2==0">{{data.date}}</td>
<td ng-if="$index %2==1">To {{data.date}}</td>
```

Will always build only one `<td>` element.

Comment: Please check my post again.

Comment: I can not understand.Could you please create one plunkr example.?

Comment: First are you sure you json is like this : " **[{{**"date":...}...}] and not like this : [[{"date":...},{..}],[{...},{...}],...]. i don't see how this can work properly.

Comment: can't go for a plunkr right now. I add another edit, let me know if you don't understand something.

Comment: Why not using this way ? If you want absolutely use the HTML <TABLE> i don't see any other way. Now if you may use a table/grid (like bootstrap grid) using <div> elements, they are plenty of new way of doing it